# unix combine grep w and v command

Tags: unix, grep

I want to search a file and include the text `#!/bin/bash`, but exclude any other line that has a # sign. These two commands: `grep -w '#!/bin/bash' file` and `grep -v '^#' file` each do one part of this job. I would like this to be a single command, so here's what I've tried.

```
grep -w '#!/bin/bash' | grep -v '^#' file
```

This excludes lines beginning with #, but doesn't include the line `#!/bin/bash`

```
grep -w '#!/bin/bash' -v '^#' file
```

This just prints every line but `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: WHY are you doing this? Comments don't slow down your script, and the minor extra space they generally add probably won't even be reflected in your disk usage due to block size. What benefit are you expecting from doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep "^[^#]\|^#\!/bin/bash$" test.sh
```

Explanation:

- `^[^#]` means starts by something different that `#`
- `\|` is a or
- `^#\!/bin/bash$` is the exact line `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: This also removes blank lines, which could affect heredocs, heretext and quoted elements within the file.

Answer (score 0):

So .. it looks as if you're trying to strip comments from bash files without removing their shebang.

The `grep` command can search for regular expressions, but isn't so good at applying rules of logic.  You *could* do something like this:

```
 grep -v '^#[^!]' input.sh
```

But you'd fail to strip comments that are affixed to the ends of lines. Note that I'm being a little more liberal with this regex, since it's entirely possible that a script might use something other than `/bin/bash` for its shebang. :-)

Another possibility would be to use `awk`. This lets you apply logic that cannot be expressed within a regular expression. For example, if you want to keep the commented line only if it is a shebang on the first line of the file, and remove all other comments, awk can express that as follows:

```
awk '
  NF==1 && /^#!/;      # if we're on the first line and find shebang, print.
  /^#/ { next }        # if this is a comment line, skip it.
  1                    # print everything else.
' input.sh
```